# How to import photos from Fan Page to a facebook profil?

Tags: facebook, post, import, comments, photos

I have some photos with some comments on my Facebook page.

And I would like to import these photos on my profile.

Is there a way to import please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know that post your profile picture with your friends comment solely is impossible. If you want to change your profile, go to your timeline. And then you will find that your empty profile picture exists left upper side. Overlap your mouse into your empty profile picture. Then you will find that 'edit profile' is popped up. Click and select photo :)